# React state doesn't update with useState

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state

I'm trying to update react state as described below. I do understand that I don't make a correct copy of the previous state, but I can't really make that to work.

```
setMainData(
  data.map((item, id) => {
    return {
      ...mainData[id],
      [`data_${id}`]: [...mainData[id][`data_${id}`], 1],
    };
  })
);
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do here is to have a structure like this:

`[{ data_0: [1]}, {data_1: [1]}]`

and after interval tick, add to array without overriding the previous state like this

`[{ data_0: [1, 2]}, {data_1: [1,2]}]`

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't update state as `map` returns a new array. Maybe there's something we are not seeing?

Comment: it does update the state, but instead of expected result i'm getting same array with new value like this: `[{ data_0: [2] }, { data_1: [2] }]`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is `data = mainData`? Did you also try getting the old state and using it instead of `mainData`? Everything looks fine to me here. Also, why is that 1 hardcoded there?

Comment: that 1 is hardcoded just for the purpose of this example, `mainData` is not `data`. `mainData` is state value and `data` is coming from the API call

Answer (score 0):

You should like this

```
const arr = data.map((item, id) => {
    return {
      ...mainData[id],
      [`data_${id}`]: [...mainData[id][`data_${id}`], 1],
    };
  })
setMainData(arr)
```

maybe its work